# Regex for parsing strings with quotes in OpenEdge data export

Tags: javascript, regex, progress-4gl

I have a data export from a Progress OpenEdge system that I want to parse in JavaScript. I would like to find all the fields of the export using a regular expression.

I have tried many things similar to this: `/("[^"]*")|[^\s]+/g` I have also tried to experiment with negative lookahead `(?!"")` but so far I have not succeeded.

A sample export output might look something similar to this:

```
12345 24,25 0 2015-06-30T14:53:14.891 "12345" "24,25" "0" "2015-06-30T14:53:14.891" "" yes no ? "String with ""quoted"" word" "String 
with a multi
line string. "" <- Just a quote
 " " This is the last value "
6789 35,36 0 2016-07-31T15:54:15.892 "6789" "35,36" "0" "2016-07-31T15:54:15.892" "" no yes ? "Just a simple string" ? ?
```

The fields are:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt_test NO-UNDO
    FIELD valueA AS INTEGER
    FIELD valueB AS DECIMAL
    FIELD valueC AS INTEGER
    FIELD valueD AS DATETIME
    FIELD valueE AS CHARACTER
    FIELD valueF AS CHARACTER
    FIELD valueG AS CHARACTER
    FIELD valueH AS CHARACTER
    FIELD valueI AS CHARACTER
    FIELD valueJ AS LOGICAL
    FIELD valueK AS LOGICAL
    FIELD valueL AS LOGICAL
    FIELD valueM AS CHARACTER
    FIELD valueN AS CHARACTER
    FIELD valueO AS CHARACTER
.
```

The export format is:
All fields are separated by a space. Strings are contained within double-quote characters ("). If there is a quote in the string that is escaped by using two double-quote characters (""). If there is an empty string that is also two double-quote characters ( "" ) but with delimiter spaces around them.

The actual data types and the fact that this is a Progress system doesn't matter, it's just to give some context to my question.

*So to summarize:* How can I write a (JavaScript compatible) regular expression that successfully separates the different parts of the exported data while ignoring the escaped double-quotes in strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is doable with one single regular expression. You're going to need a parser here. Fortunately, it will be quite easy to write, for example:

```js
str = `12345 24,25 0 2015-06-30T14:53:14.891 "12345" "24,25" "0" "2015-06-30T14:53:14.891" "" yes no ? "String with ""quoted"" word" "String
with a multi
line string. "" <- Just a quote
 " " This is the last value "
6789 35,36 0 2016-07-31T15:54:15.892 "6789" "35,36" "0" "2016-07-31T15:54:15.892" "" no yes ? "Just a simple string" ? ?`;

str = str.replace(/""/g, '@');

matches = str.match(/"([\s\S]*?)"|\S+|\n/g);

rows = [[]]

for(var m of matches) {
    if (m === '\n') {
        rows.push([]);
        continue;
    }
    if(m === '@') {
        m = '';
    }
    if (m[0] === '"') {
        m = m.slice(1, -1);
    }
    m = m.replace(/@/g, '"');
    rows[rows.length - 1].push(m)
}

console.log(rows)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was afraid that might be the case.